# Wordpress gallery urls are broken (not shows image url)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to store external images and make gallery with them. Even if 150x150 pixels thumbnails shown correctly, target image url is broken..

**here is exaple item from gallery**

```
<a href="http://domain.name/0000000135-1920x1080-18/">
    <img width="150" height="150" src="http://domain.name/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/0000000135.1920x1080-18-150x150.jpg" 
     class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail" alt="">
</a>
```

**php section;**

```
 $ids = [];
 foreach ( $game->images as $image ) {
 $_image = $this->upload_image( $image->path );
     array_push( $ids, $_image["id"] );
 }
 $imp     = implode( ",", $ids );
 $gallery = "[gallery ids='$imp']"; // I'm going to put shortcode inside of heredoc content
 $gallery = trim( $gallery, "'" );


 public function upload_image( $url ) {
    $image = [];
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    $image["src"] = media_sideload_image( $url, null, null, 'src' );
    $image["id"]  = attachment_url_to_postid( $image["src"] );

    return $image;
}
```

How do I fix this ?

Comment: I think adding an image to the Media Library also requires to create the according attachment metadata, check here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238294/programmatically-adding-images-to-the-media-library-with-wp-generate-attachment

Comment: but I don't have post id yet, I'm creating post after creating the gallery

Comment: Well have tried to add `wp generate attachment metadata` and `wp_update_attachment_metadata` before you return the `$image`?

Comment: @Michael No, I didin't, is that neccesary ? I checked https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode and it says `Specifying IDs in your shortcode allows you to include images in your gallery that aren't necessarily "attached" to your post ` so it shouldn't be a problem I guess

Comment: @Michael No, I didin't, is that neccesary ? I checked https://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode and it says `Specifying IDs in your shortcode allows you to include images in your gallery that aren't necessarily "attached" to your post ` so it shouldn't be a problem I guess

Comment: You're trying to add images programmatically to your library first, and that requires the appropriate metadata to be created! Who cares about the gallery, it just reads properly stored attachments from the DB. "Attachment" doesn't mean your image is attached to a post, it's just a Wordpress way of saying "item in media library"!

Comment: @Michael ohh I'm sorry, I didin't know that :/ so how can I add image without post id ?

Comment: By starting to read the function description, maybe? `media_sideload_image` requires a post id, which you don't have, but `wp_insert_attachment` does not. Just get your head out of your behind and have a closer look at the solution I pointed out to you.